# What is the correct attribute_set_id for customer entity and customer_address entity?

Tags: magento

I notice a discrepancy in Magento attribute_set_id for customer_address and customer entities. In customer_address_entity and customer_entity tables, the attribute_set_id is 0. However, in eav_attribute_set table, there is no such a thing where attribute_set_id is 0.

Supposedly, the attribute_set_id for customer entity is 1 and the attribute_set_id for customer_address entity 2. Is that correct?

```
attribute_set_id == 1 \\customer entity
attribute_set_id == 2 \\customer_address entity
```

Answer (score 1):

The `attribute_set_id` column in the `customer_entity` and `customer_address_entity` are useless since the customers and the adresses only use one single attribute set.
When retrieving attributes  for one of these entities the `default_attribute_set_id` from the `eav_entity_type` is used (and only that).

Comment: Although I somewhat agree with you (that's what I thought either at the first place). However, I'm still curious why Magento would do that.

Comment: @user1576748. I'm curious also. Most probably it's un-implemented feature like many others. For example in the core layout files there is this tag `<layout version="0.1.0">`. The version has no value...and there are others.